# Get all Files and Folders and subfolders from a Root Site in a tree view with C# in a PNP Core Framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, caml-query, pnp

I'm currently using PNP Core Framework with a "normal" console application.

I want to get all Files and Folders from a specific Document Library. How can I do this in a simple way? I tried it with a CAML Query approach, but no real luck.

I'm currently stuck at this question.

Best regards

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

see the following code

```
private static void UseRecursiveMethodToGetAllItems()
{
    using (var context = new ClientContext(WebUrl))
   {
        context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, Password);

        var rootFolders = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(LibName).Folders;
        context.Load(rootFolders, folders => folders.Include(f => f.ListItemAllFields));
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (var folder in rootFolders)
        {
            GetFilesAndFolders(context, folder);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

private static void GetFilesAndFolders(ClientContext context, Folder folder)
{
    if (folder != null && folder.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues.Count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Folder - {folder.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"]}");

        var fileCollection = folder.Files;
        context.Load(fileCollection, files => files.Include(f => f.ListItemAllFields));
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach(var file in fileCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($" -> {file.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"]}");
        }

        var subFolderCollection = folder.Folders;
        context.Load(subFolderCollection, folders => folders.Include(f => f.ListItemAllFields));
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (var subFolder in subFolderCollection)
        {
            GetFilesAndFolders(context, subFolder);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61323146/c-sharp-sharepoint-loop-through-all-files-in-folder-and-all-subfolders

Comment: Is this also with context.web.lists.GetBytitle("ListName") possible?

Comment: Hi, any updates?